# Android: Trying to make directory, makes file instead

Tags: android

I'm trying to create an empty directory, but instead it creates a file.

```
publicDocsPath = 
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS);

autoTestDir = new File(publicDocsPath + File.separator+"autoTest");        
autoTestDir.mkdirs();
```

I can get around it by creating a dummy file under neath it, as such

```
autoTestDir = new File(publicDocsPath + File.separator+"autoTest" + File.separator+ "nullfile");
```

But I would like to know if I'm doing something wrong or if there is a way to tell the system you want to create a directory not a file.

Note: I'm on a mac, and I'm using Android File Transfer program to verify my results. Maybe the file is being created as a directory, but issue is with Android File Transfer and it shows the directory as a file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
File documents = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS);
File dir = new File(documents.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "autoTest" + File.separator);

// creates if doesn't exists
dir.mkdir();
```

You have to add the **file separator** after "**autoTest**".

Comment: Use a slash as file separator + what is your minSdkVersion ?